# Dagger 2.10 subcomponent generator - Injector validation fails

Tags: android, annotations, generator, dagger, subcomponent

I'm trying to create an annotation processor which will process my MVP views (fragments) to auto-generated Subcomponents (similar to https://github.com/lukaspili/Auto-Dagger2, but for the new **Dagger 2.10 android injectors**)

So far, I've been able to generate appropriate files, but there is a strange error message when compiling generated components

`Error:(22, 58) error: @dagger.android.support.FragmentKey methods should bind dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>, not dagger.android.AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment>. See google.github.io/dagger/android`

The structure of Factory module and Subcomponent files should be correct, because **as soon as I copy-paste the generated classes** and create a regular classes (both Factory module and Subcomponent) and use real classes instead of generated ones, the message is no longer shown and **compilation succeeds**

It seems like the problem lies in `AndroidMapKeyValidator` ([link](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/master/java/dagger/android/processor/AndroidMapKeyValidator.java)), where `!MoreTypes.equivalence().equivalent(returnType, intendedReturnType)` call apparently fails, but I don't have much of an experience debugging annotation processors, so I don't know why precisely...

Can maybe anyone help where to search for the problem?
Thanks

FYI: `MyFragment` does extend `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

---

My files:

**Generated Factory**

`@Module
public interface BuildersModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @FragmentKey(MyFragment.class)
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment> factory(MySubcomponent.Builder builder);
}`

**Generated subcomponent**

`@Subcomponent(modules = MyModule.class)
public interface MySubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<MyFragment> {
  MyPresenter presenter();
  @Subcomponent.Builder
  abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MyFragment> {}
}`

Comment: @ I'm unable to help you with this but I'm interested in your solution, would you consider making it open source should you get it working?

Comment: @ScottCooper sure, It's planned as part of the AMF project I'm working on https://github.com/Team-SOFTsk/AMF

Comment: a little update on debugging the problem here https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested in solution:

I found out that for some reason, references of `ClassType`-s compared during project's compile time are not the same when validating generated method.

And these references, despite the fact that they are pointing to the same class, are checked for equality in `auto-common` library in `EqualVisitor.visitDeclared` method. Apparently, this can be a bug in `auto-common`, because Elements in `visitDeclared` are compared by object reference, but not type reference.

So workaround here is to **use local fixed copy** of `auto-common` library and **exclude all dependencies of the original library**.

```
//TODO think if this is the correct solution to cast both elements
//return aElement.equals(bElement)
return ((TypeElement) aElement).getQualifiedName().equals(((TypeElement) bElement).getQualifiedName())
       && equal(a.getEnclosingType(), b.getEnclosingType(), newVisiting)
       && equalLists(a.getTypeArguments(), b.getTypeArguments(), newVisiting);
```

---

I still have to check why those references are not the same, and I have to think how the equality check can be fixed properly in `auto-common` (I use just a quickfix) before filing an issue in `auto-common` repo.